# Checkout to another branch with different composer dependencies

Tags: git, composer-php

So lately I've been developing composer package and I ran into following problem.

Branch `1.0` had composer dependency on `somepackage: 1.0.0`
Branch `2.0` had composer dependency on `somepackage: 2.0.0`

Is it possible to switch between these two branches without <strike>removing `vendor` directory and</strike> running `composer update` each time after `git checkout {branch}`? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: You should probably just have two different workspaces if you have different version sets.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this within one directory :)

Comment: Why do you need to remove `vendor` dir?

Comment: @AlexanderGuz Actually I had in mind old composer bug where you could not downgrade package version. Just checked this out and it seems to work okay. However, running `composer update` each time is a little bit annoying (especially if you dependent package has a lot of other dependencies)

Comment: It is tedious, but that's how it works: if your branches have different dependencies, then you have to match dependencies with composer.

Comment: Also, why `composer update`? It should be `composer install` I guess.

Comment: @AlexanderGuz If `composer.lock` is excluded from repository (and it should be in packages) then it is not affected by `git checkout`

Comment: Well, this is just wrong: `composer.lock` is supposed to be committed to repository https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file. I'm afraid you're trying to solve a problem, just because of wrong usage of composer.

Comment: @AlexanderGuz As stated [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file) `For your library you may commit the composer.lock file if you want to. [...] If you do not want to commit the lock file and you are using git, add it to the .gitignore.`. For example [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) reposiotory does not have one

Comment: @AlexanderGuz However I think that you're right and I probably should add it to repository as it does not have effect on project that depends on this package. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is stated in the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file), `composer.lock` is supposed to be committed to repository. I'm afraid you're trying to solve a problem, just because of wrong usage of composer.